# Add New Field to File Names in Directory - R

Tags: r, filenames

I am pulling 10-Ks off the SEC website using the EDGAR package in R. Fortunately, the text files come with a consistent file naming convention: CIK number (this is a unique filing ID)_File type_Date.

Ultimately I want to analyze these by SIC/industry group, so I think the best way to do this would be to add the SIC industry code to this filename rule.

I am including an image of what I would like to do below. It is kind of like a database join except my file names would be taking the new field. Not sure how to do that, I am pretty new to R and file scripting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have a data.frame with a column `filenames`. (Or a vector containing all the filenames) See the code below:

```
# A data.frame with a character column 'filenames'
df$CIK <- sapply(df$filenames, FUN = function(x) {unlist(strsplit(x, split = "_"))[1]})
df$CIK <- as.character(df$CIK)
```

Now, let us assume that you have another data.frame with two columns: `CIK` and `SIC`.

```
# A data.frame with two character columns: 'CIK' and 'SIC'
# df2.
#
# We add another column to the first data.frame: 'new_filenames'
df$new_filename <- sapply(1:nrow(df), FUN = function(idx, CIK, filenames, df2) {
    SIC <- df2$SIC[which(df2$CIK == CIK[idx])]
    new_filename <- as.character(paste(SIC, "_", filenames[idx], sep = ""))
    new_filenames
}, CIK = df$CIK, filenames = df$filenames, df2 = df2)

# Now the new filenames are available in df$new_filenames
View(df)
```

Comment: Yes! Cool. Thank you.